# Is it possible to open multiple tabs in ConEmu and run a command in each of them with one click? (or with Autohotkey)

Tags: autohotkey, conemu

I'm developing an application that uses multiple microservices (springboot apps) that i have to start when i'm setting up the enviornment. Is the a way to open multiple tabs in ConEmu and run in them command like "Java -jar app.jar" with one click?

Or if there is no option as such, put existing powershell window inside ConEmu and make an additional tab from it?

Comment: You might want to investigate the `start-process` command  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to open multiple tabs in ConEmu and run a command in each of them with one click?

I believe that the basic answer is "Yes". Based on this [official ConEmu documentation](https://conemu.github.io/en/ConEmuArgs.html) and your `java -jar app.jar` example, you could likely use e.g.:

```
ConEmu -runlist cmd /k java -jar app.jar -cur_console:fn ^|^|^| cmd /k java -jar app.jar -cur_console:s1TVn ^|^|^| cmd /k java -jar app.jar -cur_console:s1THn ^|^|^| cmd /k java -jar app.jar -cur_console:s2THn
```

in a batch file to execute `java -jar app.jar` in four ConEmu windows at startup. So you would end up with a ConEmu instance with four split screens and each of those would have executed `java -jar app.jar`.

Comment: Will try that soon.